# TypeScript Access Static Variables Using Instances

Tags: oop, typescript

So in most OOP languages static variables can also be called **class** variables, ie their value is *shared* among all instances of this class. For example, in my game I have a class `Bullet` which is extended by `GreenBullet` and `PinkBullet`. I want these subclasses to have a "class" or "static" variable called `ammo` so that I can keep track of the ammo count for that specific ammo type. But here is the catch: I want to be able to access this property through an instance of the subclass.

Example:

```
var bullet: GreenBullet = new GreenBullet()
if (bullet.ammo <= 0)
    return;
bullet.shoot();
bullet.ammo --;
```

I want ALL instances of `GreenBullet` to be aware of this change to their ammo count.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First option is to create instance accessors to static variable:

```
class GreenBullet
{
   static ammo: number = 0;
   get ammo(): number { return GreenBullet.ammo; }
   set ammo(val: number) { GreenBullet.ammo = val; }
}
var b1 = new GreenBullet();
b1.ammo = 50;
var b2 = new GreenBullet();
console.log(b2.ammo); // 50
```

If you want all subclasses of `Bullet` (including itself) to have separate ammo count, you can make it that way:

```
class Bullet
{
   static ammo: number = 0;
   get ammo(): number { return this.constructor["ammo"]; }
   set ammo(val: number) { this.constructor["ammo"] = val; }
}
class GreenBullet extends Bullet { }
class PinkBullet extends Bullet { }

var b1 = new GreenBullet();
b1.ammo = 50;
var b2 = new GreenBullet();
console.log(b2.ammo); // 50
var b3 = new PinkBullet();
console.log(b3.ammo); // 0
```

On a side note, I'm fairly sure you should not store bullet count in a static variable.

Comment: Nice trick with the separate static members. How did you get "this.constructor.ammo" to compile? casting to Any?

Comment: @MichaelS that or do `this.constructor["ammo"]`. Also, I would suggest to make `static ammo` private since there's no need for anything outside the class to access it.