# How to access a static variable from a generic class?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have many class with their static variables, like this:

**user.ts:**

```
export class User {
  static modelKey = 'user';

  // other variables
}
```

**car.ts:**

```
export class Car {
  static modelKey = 'car';

  // other variables
}
```

And somewhere I want just call the `DataSource` (see below) like this:

```
const dataSource = new DataSource<Car>();
```

**data-source.ts:**

```
export class DataSource<T> {

  constructor() {
    console.log(T.modelKey); // won't compile
  }  
}
```

Of course, it won't compile because I can't simple use `T.<variable>`. So, my question is: how can I accomplish this?

[**Playground**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20modelKey%20%3D%20'user'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20variables%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20modelKey%20%3D%20'car'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20variables%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20DataSource%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(T.modelKey)%3B%20%2F%2F%20won't%20compile%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Don't know much about typescript but it looks like you are trying to access a variable from T, which has no definition of the variable modelKey inside it. It would maybe be better to ask for an abstract variable that is a parent of Car and User in the constructor and use that instead of T.

Comment: @ElijahSeedArita can you elaborate? Mind to reproduce it in [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)? Thanks.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407697/typescript-access-static-variables-using-instances) out. EDIT: don't trust me look at GregL's answer

Answer (score 2):

You can't access properties on types, only on arguments passed in, because types don't exist at runtime.

But you can pass in your class to your constructor, and then access properties on that.

e.g.

```
export class User {
  static modelKey = 'user';

  // other variables
}
export class Car {
  static modelKey = 'car';

  // other variables
}

interface ModelClass<T> {
  new (): T;
  modelKey: string;
}

export class DataSource<T> {

  constructor(clazz: ModelClass<T>) {
    console.log('Model key: ', clazz.modelKey); // will compile
  }  
}

new DataSource(Car);
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20modelKey%20%3D%20'user'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20variables%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20modelKey%20%3D%20'car'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20variables%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20DataSource%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(T.modelKey)%3B%20%2F%2F%20won't%20compile%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0D%0A%7D#src=export%20class%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20modelKey%20%3D%20'user'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20variables%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20modelKey%20%3D%20'car'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20variables%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ModelClass%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new%20()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20modelKey%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20DataSource%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(clazz%3A%20ModelClass%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('Model%20key%3A%20'%2C%20clazz.modelKey)%3B%20%2F%2F%20won't%20compile%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20DataSource(Car)%3B#src=export%20class%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20modelKey%20%3D%20'user'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20variables%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20modelKey%20%3D%20'car'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20variables%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ModelClass%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new%20()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20modelKey%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20DataSource%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(clazz%3A%20ModelClass%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('Model%20key%3A%20'%2C%20clazz.modelKey)%3B%20%2F%2F%20won't%20compile%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20DataSource(Car)%3B#src=export%20class%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20modelKey%20%3D%20'user'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20variables%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20static%20modelKey%20%3D%20'car'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20other%20variables%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ModelClass%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new%20()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20modelKey%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20DataSource%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(clazz%3A%20ModelClass%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('Model%20key%3A%20'%2C%20clazz.modelKey)%3B%20%2F%2F%20won't%20compile%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20DataSource(Car)%3B)

Comment: Thanks, although it might work correctly on playground, I'm getting the following error in my project: `'Argument of type' type of car 'is not attributable to the parameter of type' ModelClass <T> '` when I try to do `new DataSource(Car);`. I suspect that's because TS 2.4.x introduced better checking for generics. In my project I'm using the latest version of TS (2.4.2) and the playground uses the 2.3.3 (I think). Can you help me?

Comment: Full error `[ts]
Argument of type 'typeof Car' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ModelClass<T>'.
  Type 'Car' is not assignable to type 'T'.`

Comment: I manage to make it work excluding generic from `ModelClass`: `interface ModelClass {...}` and also removing the `new()` completely. Is it the right approach to go?

Comment: @dev_054: The issue is probably that your project's `Car` class doesn't have a no-arg constructor.  To make @GregL's code work with any class, you should change `new (): T` to `new (...args: any[]): T`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that if you want to use `T`'s static properties like `clazz.modelKey` inside a `DataSource` method other than the constructor, you should store `clazz` as an instance property; the easiest way to do that is to declare the `clazz` parameter as `public` (i.e., `constructor(public clazz: ModelClass<T>)`).